# Random.Next() sometimes returns same number in separate threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, random

I have the following class

```
class Program
{
   static Random _Random = new Random();

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      ...
      for (int i = 0; i < no_threads; ++i)
      {
         var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Send));
         thread.Start();
      }
      ...   
   }

   static void Send()
   {
      ...
      int device_id = _Random.Next(999999);
      ...
   }
}
```

The code creates the specified number of threads, starts each one, and assigns each thread a random `device_id`. For some reason, the first two threads that are created often have the same `device_id`. I can't figure out why this happens.

Comment: This is statistically correct, as if you throw 2 dice they sometime give you the same number, plus Random is not thread safe -> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx

Comment: @Mitch: None of the linked questions are dealing with the same situation. It's only the thread safety which is relevant here, as there's only one instance of Random.

Comment: @Jon: yeah, that's true.

Comment: By the sound of things, if two threads end up with the same device_id, it's causing you a problem. If that's the case, then you shouldn't be using *random* assignments anyway - you should do something that *guarantees* that there are no collisions.

Comment: @dvvh: yeah, but the intraval is big enough so that a collission shouldn't happen every other run. The problem has been eliminated, tho.

Comment: @damien...: obviously, but this is just a proof of concept app anyway.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Note: The most appropriate approach as of .NET 6 would be to use [Random.Shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.shared?view=net-8.0) which is thread-safe.

---

Random is not thread-safe - you shouldn't be using the same instance from multiple threads. It can get much worse than just returning the same data - by using it from multiple threads, you can get it "stuck" in a state where it will *always* return 0, IIRC.

Obviously you don't just want to create a new instance for each thread at roughly the same time, as they'll end up with the same seeds...

I have an [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) which goes into the details of this and provides an implementation which lazily instantiates one instance of `Random` per thread using an incrementing seed.

Comment: I suspected as much but wasn't sure even after checking MSDN. I'll check out your article as well. Thanks.

Comment: See also Jon Skeet's [MiscUtil.StaticRandom](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/).

Comment: (...a few years later)
There is now a `Random.Shared` that is thread-safe

Comment: @JimAho: Thanks, I'll add that in an edit.

Answer (score 5):

Random is a pseudo-random number generator and there's nothing preventing it from returning same result for multiple calls. After all there's a probability for this happening. Not to mention that according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx):

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

So you shouldn't be calling the [Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5.aspx) method at all from multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

Your example code only shows one use of `_Random` per thread.  Assuming this is the case, you could also generate the random number in the main `for` loop and pass the random number into each thread as a parameter.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < no_threads; ++i)
 {
      var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Send));
      thread.Start(_Random.Next(999999));
 }
```

and then modify your thread function to accept the parameter:

```
 static void Send(int device_id)
 {
    ...
    //int device_id = _Random.Next(999999);
    ...
 }
```