# Regex - Improve search and add third group

Tags: c#, regex, .net-3.5

This is kind of improvement of my previous question: [c# generate random string based on pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396482/c-sharp-generate-random-string-based-on-pattern)

I have code as below:

```
class Generator
{
    private static readonly Random R = new Random();
    private static readonly char[] L = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
    private static readonly char[] U = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };
    private static readonly char[] S = { '!', '@', '#', '$', '%' };

    public static string FromPattern(string pattern)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\[([Ccds])(?::([\d]+))?\]", ReplaceSingleMatch);
    }

    private static string ReplaceSingleMatch(Match m)
    {
        int length;
        if (!int.TryParse(m.Groups[2].Value, out length))
            length = 1;

        var output = new StringBuilder();
        while (output.Length != length)
        {
            switch (m.Groups[1].Value)
            {
                case "d"://digits
                    output.Append(R.Next(0, 9));
                    break;
                case "c"://lowercase char
                    output.Append(L[R.Next(L.Length)]);
                    break;
                case "C"://uppercase char
                    output.Append(U[R.Next(U.Length)]);
                    break;
                case "s"://special char
                    output.Append(S[R.Next(S.Length)]);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```

Using above I can write:

```
Generator.FromPattern("ID: [d:3][c:2]#[C][s:2]")
```

And I will get sample output like : `ID: 263ac#D$!`

So when I enter `[d]` I get single digit, if I enter `[d:5]` I get 5 digits.

What I would like to add is range, so when I enter `[d:2-5]` I would get randomly from 2 to 5 random digits.

My biggest problem is regex, rest is easy :)

I need my regex to search below groups:

- `[d]`,
- `[d:3]` (it must be number after colon),
- `[d:2-5]` (two numbers separated by dash)

**Any suggestion about improvements are welcome!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome tool for regular expressions : http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Here's the expression I came up with (with named capture groups) :

```
\[(?<type>[Ccds])(:(?<a>[\d]+)(-(?<b>[\d]+))?)?\]
```

[image]